# Android add image to button

Tags: android, image, button

I want to add an image to a `Button` (no `imagebutton`, as the particular button can either contain text or an image; plus the imagebutton has the same problem), while still retaining the original android-style button. So adding `android:background` in the XML doesn't cut it, as that will remove the android default button with rounded corners etc. `(android.R.drawable.btn_default)`

Is this in any way possible?

I think one way is to make a `9patch` image for the button pressed (one for up and one for down) and `onTouch Action_DOWN` make a layered background drawable and put that onto the button, and doing the same thing but with another `9patch` for `onTouch Action_UP`, but I think that will decrease the performance of the application substantially, as that will require quite a lot of resource reading and layer merging for all the button clicks (and for my application, that will be quite a lot). Is what I state above correct?

EDIT: I can't declare the source of the image in the XML, because I get the images from a web service, so anything can be put on the Buttons, but it has to happen programmatically.

Comment: you can set backgroundDrawable anyTime you want with setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.my_selector) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492064/android-add-image-to-button/12492097#12492097

Comment: so what about the image i get via the web service?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can be done using the `android:drawableTop`, `android:drawableBottom`, `android:drawableLeft`, `android:drawableRight` attributes in your layout.xml.

Comment: In code, you can use the - strangly named - method `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)` as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int) <-- link is not linked correctly by SO...

Comment: Just read that you get the images from a webservice, so you better use this method then: `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)`. You can create the Drawables using `Drawable.createFromStream(InputStream is)`.

Comment: How can I resize images used like this?

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
     <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/home_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="6dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="AndroidDhina"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Set below Property of Button for Display Image with Text, using this property image is displaying above text.

```
<Button android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For setting Image :

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

For setting text :

```
btn.setText("My Button");
```

Code :

```
private Drawable buttonDrawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonDrawable=btn.getBackground();
    //Setting the image.
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Removing image and setting text*/
            btn.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
            btn.setText("My Button");   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: won't work, because I want to retain the Android styled buttons. when i set the background, the android original is gone and replaced for a potentially squared button. I want the image on/in the button, not instead of the original button layout

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own drawable with multiple states and set that to background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

Drawables can have rounded corners like so.

```
<corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0.2dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.2dp"/>
```