# Adding images to buttons in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

How to put images on ListView buttons? I found some tutorials but don't know how to implement in my xml that I have already. I still working only with `xml` files and didn't touch anything in the code of the generated `MainActivity.java`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the current xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/food" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:text="@string/Menu1" />
    <!-- android:background="#c5e1b0" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:text="@string/Menu2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:text="@string/Menu3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:text="@string/Menu4" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So I want to add images on the left side of this 4 buttons.

Anyone can help with this task?
Update:

Currently I have this structure on the left. Half of the screen (upper) is image. Second half I have 4 buttons. I want to put image on each button on the left side like is in the right picture with where is red aquare.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android add image to button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492064/android-add-image-to-button)

Comment: can you draw and upload a hand draw of your list item so tha I can help you

Comment: As @ChVKishore said, is it how your each item will look like in the list ?

Comment: Updated and sorry for my drawing skills. Image on left and text next to image.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258386/how-to-add-imageleft-and-text-on-button

Comment: @JibranKhan, from your link I think this can do what I need `use android:DrawableLeft="@drawable/image" in your xml`

Comment: Yes as i also mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can have image and Text both on same button

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Testing" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"/>
```